# particular day last record retrieving from database....?

Tags: mysql, sql

field structure image as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0gu.png)

data saved in column as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUhJT.png)

I am not getting particular day's last record...?
say I know a date 2022-01-20 then I want this day last record from table..? how to query ?

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far? normally you would order by date descending and select the first record

Answer (score 0):

Query would need to get the results by considering the time.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created_at > '2022-01-20 00:00:00' AND created_at < '2022-01-20 23:59:59' Order by created_at DESC LIMIT 1.
```

This will give you last record of 2022-01-20.